# Creating instance of similar types with content using Generics in C#

Tags: .net, generics

I have two different class definitions C1 and C2 which both have a property called 
    DateTime Start;

So

```
public partial class C1
{
    public DateTime Start;
}
public partial class C2
{
    public DateTime Start;
}
```

Because the two classes are somewhat alike, I would like a smart way to create  instances of those classes, and I was thinking if it was possible to combine it in a generic method that returns an instance of one of the above classes with the Start property assigned:
I was thinking of something like:

```
public T GetClassInstance<T>(DateTime start) where T : new()
{
    T time = new T();
    time.Start = start;
    return time;
}
```

but the above gives a compile error because T.Start is not defined.

I know I can add a constraint but that only goes for one class:

```
public T GetClassInstance<T>(DateTime start) where T : C1, new()
```

but I get a compile error if I add more class there.

Moreover I cannot redefine my classes to implement a common interface, because they are generated from an XSD which I may not edit

Any suggestions to a smart way I can achieve the above?

Thanks
Jeeji

Comment: Define an interface with the common members and use that.

Comment: Can you implement common interface in both types? If not, just use `dynamic` (though I'm not a fan of it)

Comment: How would I use 'dynamic'?

Comment: "the two classes are somewhat alike" - by that logic a monkey and a potato are "somewhat alike" because they both have "eyes".  You _could_ use dynamic or reflection but both are susceptible to run-time errors.

Comment: Is that the only property that each has or just the only one that they have in _common_?

Comment: That is not the only one they have in common. And you are right. They are not somewhat alike. I was wrong to say so. But what if all their properties were alike, would there be an elegant way? –

Comment: @JihadHaddad Not without a base class or interface defining those properties.  What you are describing is [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) which is possible only via reflection and/or `dynamic` in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use interface as the others suggesed. The generated class usually a partial class, is it partial in your case? So you can add interface implementation in the partial part, and not in the generted code.

Here is an example:

```
public partial class C1
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}
public partial class C2
{
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public interface IClass
{
    DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public partial class C1 : IClass { }
public partial class C2 : IClass { }

static T SetTime<T>(DateTime time) where T: IClass, new()
{
    var t = new T();
    t.Time = DateTime.Now;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Correct, but might benefit from an example.

Comment: Yes perfect. I edited my above question to include that the classes are partial.

Answer (score 1):

Define an interface

```
public interface IHasStartTime // please think of a more descriptive name!
{
    DateTime Start {get;set;}
}
```

Implement it on both `C1` and `C2`, and use that as your constraint

```
public T GetClassInstance<T>(DateTime start) where T : IHasStartTime, new()
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reimplement the classes. They are generated by and XSD which I cannot control.

Comment: Those sort of generators usually produce a `partial` class, which means you can create another file which is also `partial` which includes your interface implementation.